# How to pass arguments for powershell script in xaml build definition

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, azure-devops, build-definition

For continous delivery, i need to pass two parameters to a powershell script which is planned to run after VSTS build for copying files from drop folder to deploy location. Note that the build server and the server where the files are dropped are different. There is a column named `PostBuildScriptArgs` in the xaml build template. but could not find from anywhere how to pass two arguments in one column. what is the format for that? can anybody help

[image: my xaml build definition]

Comment: The default build process template do not contain PostBuildScriptArgs are you using some customize xaml build template, could you double confirm it works well about passing arguments?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT i am now trying to add that. however i cannot use `invokeprocess` activity into the tool bar

Comment: showing `could not load file or assembly 'libgit2sharp.gitserver'` error while adding `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow` in the tool box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameters with their names. see for example below.

```
-Param1Name 'Param1value' -param2Name param2value -verbose
```

So your one should be

```
-Source 'sourcepath' -Destination 'Destinationpath'
```

Comment: @NithinChandran the suggestion from ChamindaC is correct. Your screenshot shows that you are using the wrong syntax. Furthermore parameter names must match those in the Powershell script. Have you checked this basic things? What are you using now?

Comment: @GiulioVian syntax may be correct. But now i strongly assume that the script is not getting executed in the build server. While analyzing the process template xaml file the `PostBuildScriptPath` or `PostBuildScriptArgs` arguments are not calling anywhere. This may be the issue